# Why can't I make a postfix operator named '!'

Tags: swift

I try to make a postfix operator, but it gives me the error "Cannot declare a custom postfix '!' operator"

```
postfix operator !
postfix func !(lhs: UInt) -> Double {
    var res = 1.0

    for multiplier in 1...lhs {
        res *= Double(multiplier)
    }

    return res
}
```

I did not expect the error. How can I fix this?

Comment: From the [documentation](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/LexicalStructure.html#ID418): *"... the postfix operators >, !, and ? are reserved. These tokens can’t be overloaded, nor can they be used as custom operators."*

Comment: It would be too confusing. I'm not saying this is a good idea, but you could use this: `postfix operator ❗️` see my gist for allowed operators: https://gist.github.com/Sajjon/8c227a8610efa58fa6c3bea2ee2cdfa1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just realised:

In the documentation it says the postfix operators >, !, ? are 'reserved'. This means it is not allowed by swift to create postfix operators with this name.